# Backend and frontend technologies compatible with Tizen, WebOS, Android TV, Apple tvOS and Roku OS

Tags: tvos, tizen, android-tv, webos, smart-tv

I want to develop a simple app that works on all smart tv systems: Tizen, WebOS, Android TV, Apple tvOS and Roku OS.

The app will be very simple. Its goal is to print the data from the backend in a nice way. For the initial example I wanted to print out a string stored in the backend ("Hello World") on the display.

At first I tried C++ QT/QML. I started with Tizen, but here the problems started (Tizen QT seems not to be officially supported and the community project died in 2017). The rest of the system also didn't look promising.

So my question is: What technologies/frameworks/languages should I use to achieve simple applications compatible with all those systems?

Comment: How about to try Web Application?

Answer (score 1):

Depend on the functionalities of the app. You can use `react native` for Apple TV and Android TV and `react` for the remains .But if the budget is quite tight, the `renative.org` is worth to consider.